# mean curvature is not preserved under isometry

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

I know that mean curvature is not intrinsic, so it seems that it is not preserved under isometry. What is the example that isometry does not preserve mean curvature?

Comment: $X(u,v)=(u,v,0)$,$Y(u,v)=(cosu,sinu,v)$ will it be the example?

Comment: I am sure that if you pick the very first example you've seen of an isometry you'd see that it does not preserve mean curvature. Have you actually tried?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez yes I figured it out just after i posted the question Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rolling up a plane into a cylinder can be given by the map
$$\phi(x,y) = (\cos x,\sin x,y)$$
The derivatives are easily computed,
$$\phi_{x} = (-\sin x,\cos x,0)$$
$$\phi_{y} = (0,0,1)$$
These are orthonormal with respect to the (induced) metric on the cylinder, so the parametrisation is an isometry. The plane has mean curvature $0$ while the cylinder has mean curvature $-1/2$